# How to use nuget to include portaudio package for C++

Tags: nuget, portaudio

I’m trying to build a simple audio program in C++ that was generated by ChatGPT in VisualStudio Community Edition 2022. The code uses the portaudio package. How do I use the Nuget package manager to pull this package?
I downloaded the portaudio package from a search, but the directory is
C:\Users<Myname>\vcpkg\buildtrees
I don't know how to add this directory to the project properties, or better, how to make nuget download it automatically to the right place.
If answer is complicated or obvious to experienced coders, can you point me to a reference site?
Many thanks.